# Compose app crashes on dispatchTouchEvent

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a crash event listed repeatedly in my Play Store dashboard. All instances come from Samsung Galaxy S series devices.

I am not able to reproduce this crash on any of my devices nor emulators and the stack trace does not include any part of my code.

The only thing I could deduce from this trace was that, this is happening on some touch event, but that is hardly a clue.

I'm putting the complete stack trace here hoping someone could suggest an idea.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
      at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure (MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:177)
      at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded (MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:228)
      at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded (MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
      at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout (MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:201)
      at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout (AndroidComposeView.android.kt:662)
      at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc (AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1073)
      at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent (AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1059)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3923)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3597)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3923)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3597)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3923)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3597)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3923)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3597)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:1015)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1962)
      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent (Dialog.java:1264)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:973)
      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:15335)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7794)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:7567)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:6901)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:6958)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6924)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:7122)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:6932)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:7179)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:6905)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:6958)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:6924)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:6932)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:6905)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:10354)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:10202)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:10158)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:10486)
      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:259)
      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents (Native Method)
      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java:239)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput (ViewRootImpl.java:10434)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:10575)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1108)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:866)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:789)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1092)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8663)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was, I had a LazyColumn inside an AlertDialog and the exception was raised when the LazyColumn was scrolling on relatively long lists. Apparently that would cause Compose to lose track of its measurements.

And I was too quick to pin it on Galaxy phones (sorry Samsung!)

The trick was to use [MaterialDialog](https://github.com/vanpra/compose-material-dialogs) instead of the standard AlertDialog.